# Prove that it is impossible that every non-identity element of $G$ has an order of $2$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> Let $G$ be an abelian group of order $6$. Prove that it is impossible that every non-identity element of $G$ has an order of $2$.
>
> (*Hint*: Construct a subgroup of order $4$ and get a contradiction.)

---

What i tried:

Following the hint, I know that if i can construct a subgroup of order $4$ it would be a contradiction straight away because by Lagrange theorem, the order of a subgroup must be a divisor of the order of a group and $4$ is not a divisor of $6$.

I let $H$ represent the subgroup and that $H$ has an order of $4$ and thus have $4$ elements. Also every non identity element of $H$ must have an order of $2$.

The subgroup that i have is $H=<1,r,m,rm>$

where $r$ stands for rotation and $m$ stands for reflection.
Am i correct? Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$

Comment: Note that the fact that every element has order $2$ implies that $G$ must be abelian: indeed, for $x,y \in G$ it holds that $xy = xy(yx)^2 = xyyxyx = xxyx = yx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $x,y$ be different elements of the group (not equal to the identity). Can you show that $\{e,x,y,xy\}$ forms a subgroup?

Comment: The subgroup i have in mind is $H=<1,r,m,rm>$. Is that correct?

Comment: What is $r$? What is $m$? Note that we are given *any* group $G$ with $6$ elements, so we have no idea what the elements of $G$ are.

Comment: Im using the Dihedral group $D_{3}$ as the group and $D_{2}$ as the subgroup as the example here where $r$ stands for rotation and $m$ stands for reflection.

Comment: You cannot use the dihedral group $D_3$ as the group. You have to prove something for every possible group with six element, not for one specific group. Apart from that, $D_3$ is not abelian.